# How to Access and Extract unique id's from all the rows each row having its own unique id as a key?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, subquery, nested-json

I have a JSON nested Data in column name `response` of a table name `data_1` as i am using `JSON_EXTRACT` function in my google bigquery but don't know key. talking about each row have its own key (https://i.stack.imgur.com/f1IcE.png) how to access and extract under the unique id key of nested json. as i have done till `response.data.menus.`

```
SELECT response.data.menus FROM tablename LIMIT 1000;
```